# How the operator "delete this" do exactly?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I just test the operator about "delete this".With handle system call "new/delete" will lose one overwrite delete function call.

The handle function is like:

```
inline void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* p = ::malloc( size );
    fprintf( stderr, "new size %ld: %p\n", size, p );
    return p; 
}

inline void* operator new[]( size_t size )
{
    void* p = ::malloc( size );
    fprintf( stderr, "new size[] %ld: %p\n", size, p );
    return p; 
}

inline void  operator delete(void* p)    
{
    fprintf( stderr, "delete: %p\n", p );
    ::free(p); 
}

inline void  operator delete[](void* p)  
{
    fprintf( stderr, "delete []: %p\n", p );
    ::free(p); 
}
```

and test class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A() : a(NULL)
        {
            printf( "A construct\n" );
            a = new int[100];
        }

        ~A()
        {
            printf( "A destruct \n" );
            freeA();
        }

        void freeA()
        {
            if ( a ) { delete [] a; a = NULL; }
        }

        void release()
        {
            delete this;
        }

    private:
        int*    a;
};
```

When I call

```
A* a = new A();
a->release();
```

The result is :

```
new size 8: 0x5642fc1c4e70
A construct
new size[] 400: 0x5642fc1c52a0
A destruct 
delete []: 0x5642fc1c52a0
```

missing a delete call about A( 0x5642fc1c4e70 ),why?

Comment: Did you forget to call `freeA`?

Comment: @melpomene I think that it is minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @BartekPL It's not: https://ideone.com/P93JmR

Comment: If you used ideone page, so you need just use [its template](https://ideone.com/ibIvk6)  ;)

Comment: Sorry. I just found the problem: with inline, the operator delete(void* p) can not call at all. But delete[](void* p) can.

Comment: `if (a)` is not needed before a `delete`. From C++11 `nullptr` should be used instead of `NULL`.

Comment: The behaviour of replacements of any variant of `operator new` or `operator delete` is undefined if they are specified to be `inline`.   Remove the `inline` keyword.   Omitting a call of one or more of them, if it is defined inline, is within the realms of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/replacement.functions#3

> The program's definitions are used instead of the default versions
>   supplied by the implementation ([support.dynamic]). Such replacement
>   occurs prior to program startup ([basic.def.odr], [basic.start]). The
>   program's declarations shall not be specified as inline. No diagnostic
>   is required.

That are the rules. Inline not allowed. That's the reason you are missing one delete and it works without the inline specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem: with inline, the operator delete(void* p) can not call at all. But delete[](void* p) can. 
Now I will close this.

Comment: Why it cannot be called?

Comment: I also confused. But it works if I remove the inline.You can try. I guess maybe it depends on compiler.

Comment: What you describe here is not the problem.  It is a symptom that you happen to be seeing.     The problem is that, since you have defined the operators `inline`, that the behaviour of your program is undefined.    Not calling a function that you expect will be called is a perfectly acceptable and even reasonable outcome of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes.I found the introduction in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Answer (score 0):

I running your code below c++14, your `delete` operator can be called correctly.

https://onlinegdb.com/S1zAgzXbB

However,  running over version c++14(include c++14), then need to change your code from  `inline void  operator delete(void* p)`   to `inline void  operator delete(void* p,std::size_t sz)`  or delete the `inline` keyword. then your code will be run correctly

https://onlinegdb.com/BJ3hMz7WH

hope it will be helped to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined a destructor there is no need to define the release function. Use delete directly on the pointer of the instance

Instead of

```
A* a = new A();
a->release();
```

you would have

```
A* a = new A();
delete a;
```

deleting a will call the ~A() destructor